# Is there a Patent-to-English dictionary?

Tags: claims, usa, terminology

On another site, I learned that many words in U.S. patents have very specific meanings, subtly different from their usual meanings in English.

For example, "comprising" is different from "consisting of".

What other examples are there? Is there a comprehensive list?

Comment: And it gets worse if you look internationally. In Australia, comprising can sometimes have the same meaning as "consisting of". But only sometimes.

Comment: But I recall looking for such a resource some years back while I was training some staff, and come up short. So I fear the answer may be "no" to the comprehensive list. But hopefully I'm wrong in this, because such a resource would be immensely helpful.

Comment: It would need someone with good resources to check the case law and compile a list of which words may be interpreted in what way. I think mpep has some of the definitions, but I haven't found anything like you ask for.

Comment: I found your question when searching for something similar. Here's a list that's moderately comprehensive.
http://www.pubpat.org/assets/files/garrodglossaries/GarrodMechElectroMechMedDevGlossaryv1.4a.pdf

Answer (score -1):

2 types of these language are used: A) Transitional phrases and B) Connecting clauses.
A) Transitional Phases: The transitional phrases “comprising”, “consisting essentially of”, “consisting of” and "having" define the scope of a claim. Transitional Phases defines what is included and what is not included.
"comprising”, also refer as “including,” “containing,” or “characterized by,” is inclusive or open-ended and does not exclude additional step/method/ingredients.
“consisting of” excludes any element, step, or ingredient not specified in the claim. This is why most of the Pharma company patents include consisting of.
“consisting essentially of” it basically limits the scope of a claim to the specified materials or steps but do not materially affect the basic and novel characteristic of the claimed invention.
“having” it is interpreted in light of the specification to determine whether open or closed claim language is intended.

B) Connecting clauses
Wherein
Whereby
Adapted to
Adapted for
Preferably
May
Optional
Not essential
Essential

I have mentioned about few key features. Others can even include in this one.

For further information, there are few links https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2111.html, http://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/caselaw/2016/e/clr_ii_e_1_13.htm